# How do you change the default document viewer to Okular?

Tags: okular, document-management

I have just started using Okular and I love it. It has a lot of functionality that I need when I am in pdfs and it already opens up epubs automatically. How to I get it to open pdfs by default instead of "Document Viewer?"

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/), Right click the file of the format you want, select `properties`:

[image]

Go to the `open with` tab, select the program you want to be the default for that type of file, then press the button `Set as Default`:

[image]

Comment: This only works when opening the file from the file manager, not when opening it from another program like Calibre.

Comment: Worked with 14.04 LTS

Comment: Worked with 17.04.

Answer (score 13):

Well, none of the other answers worked on 14.04, Okular simply doesn't show up in the list. But this worked perfectly:

```
mimeopen -d myfile.pdf
```

It will give you a list of applications that can open the file, and will also update the default application for you.

```
$ mimeopen -d myfile.pdf
Please choose a default application for files of type application/pdf

1) Print Preview  (evince-previewer)
2) Xournal  (xournal)
3) MuPDF  (mupdf)
4) Adobe Reader 9  (AdobeReader)
5) GIMP Image Editor  (gimp)
6) Document Viewer  (evince)
7) Other...

use application
```

Selecting one of these will set it as the default for `application/pdf` file types. You can easily set any executable to be the default by using the `Other...` option:

```
use application #7
use command: okular
Opening "myfile.pdf" with usr (application/pdf)
```

Aside: If `okular` doesn't work, you might want to try entering the full path (`usr/bin/okular`). You can find out where Okular is located by running `which okular`.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: @systemovich I think you can also just put `okular` instead of the full path, that should solve the problem with mimeopen thinking the application is called `usr`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `okular` instead of `/usr/bin/okular`. This should fix some naming issues in menus where it would otherwise say `usr` instead of `okular`.

Comment: In my case the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/204826/446253 worked with 14.04

Comment: Works even if myfile.pdf is not a real file!

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 14.04, the file you need to edit is :~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

The name of okular may varies. Someone may also find that there is no "**Set as default**" button.

So follow these steps:

```
Step 1: Right click on any pdf file => Open with => find Okular
```

The name of okular applications now should be specified in mimeapps.list. Now move to step 2.

```
Step 2: gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

Step 3: Find okular in [Added association] and copy to [Default application] section.
In my case, it is 'application/pdf=kde4-okularApplication_pdf.desktop;'
```

And you are done.

Answer (score 3):

First open a terminal and use this command:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
```

After opening it, Under the `[Default Applications]` section add a line like this

```
application/pdf=okular.desktop;
```

Now save the file and exit gedit.

Comment: I'd add a note to make a backup first.

Answer (score 2):

In short, if I remember correctly :

- Right click on a PDF,
- Properties,
- Open with,
- Select an app,
- Set as default.

Answer (score 0):

Use file manager (Dolphin in my case), select a file of the .pdf format, right click and select Properties (or Alt-Return), then click on the "File Type Options" and put your favorite viewer on top of the list (you may need to add one), **and if it doesn't help**, remove the one that is currently offered in the application (e.g. "Document Viewer") from which you want to open your file in Okular (Firefox in my case), even if it is not the first one on the list.
Worked on 20.04.5 LTS with KDE.